# What is wrong with this loop-based function that returns the position of an element?

Tags: c++, function, loops

This function looks for an integer 'key' in a given vector from a position 'start'. It returns the position of key if it finds it. But if it does not find key, it should return -1.

However, it is only returning -1 as the output. The function works fine if the else statement is removed, but obviously I need it.

So what is wrong in this function? Please explain in simple terms, I am new to C++. Thank you for all your help.

```
int Sequential_Search(const vector<int>&v, int key, int start){
    int result = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = start; i < v.size(); i++){
        if(v[i] == key){
                result = i; 
                }
        else{
            result = -1;
        }
    }
    return result;  
}
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need the else block, you could instead set `int result = -1;` at the start of the function and you would not need the else block within the loop. The -1 is likely returning because the loop continues even after the item is found until the loop finishes. If your coding standard allows, you could also add a `break;` after the point where you set `result = i;`.

Comment: Please also consider learning how `std::find(std::begin(v) + start, std::end(v), key)` works.

Comment: @Wyck I saw a lot of that online, I hope my class gets to that soon:)

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty easy to understand:

```
 for(i = start; i < v.size(); i++){
        if(v[i] == key){
                result = i; 
                }
        else{
            result = -1;
        }
    }
```

Let's say your vector contains [1, 2, 3, 4] and you search 2 starting at index 0: here is what your code is doing:

```
i = 0: (v[i] : 1) == 2 -> false: result = -1
i = 1: (v[i] : 2) == 2 -> true: result = 1
i = 2: (v[i] : 3) == 2 -> false: result = -1
i = 3: (v[i] : 4) == 2 -> false: result = -1
```

When you've found your value, you still continue to read other value whereas you should stop.

- Either using `break` or directly returning (`return i`) in the `v[i] == key` condition;
- Either by checking result in the for condition (`result == -1 && i < v.size()`)

Per comment remark: the case with `break` and `return` (the last one is not so hard):

```
int Sequential_Search(const vector<int>&v, int key, int start){
  int result = -1; // important for 'break'
  for(int i = start; i < v.size(); i++){
     if(v[i] == key){
       result = i; break;
     }
  }
  return result;  
}

int Sequential_Search(const vector<int>&v, int key, int start){
  for(int i = start; i < v.size(); i++){
     if(v[i] == key){
       return i;
     }
  }
  return -1;  
}
```

Comment: I think you should show a completely repaired version -- probably using `return i`, especially since a `break` alone won't fix it because it would return 0 for an empty vector.

Comment: Alas, I wish I had known about breaks. Well, now I do. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

When the loop finds the key, it sets `result = i` - but it doesn't stop looping. On the next iteration, `v[i]` is likely not equal to `key`, and the loop resets `result` to `-1`. The function returns `-1` unless `key` just happens to match the last element.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is failing with the else statement is because there are many scenarios that the key would not be the last item in the vector.

If the key is 3 and the vector of ints if <1,3,4>, the for loop will loop through 3 times total. On the first iteration, it will go into the else statement since we did not find the key at the 0th index. Result is -1. On the second iteration, we found the key! Set result to i = 1. The third iteration will go into the else statement again, and set the result back to -1.

To fix this, you can use 'break' to leave the for loop as soon as you find result. Set result to I and then follow that with break; This will ensure that if the result is found, you will not go into the else statement again and reset it to -1.